# .Net HMAC and base64 Encoding Issue

Tags: c#, .net, hash, base64, hmac

I am trying to create a base64-encoded HMAC SHA512 hash using a secret of `secret` and a payload of `foo`. I am unable to make my .NET code produce the correct value. I am wondering if the encoding is the underlying issue.

Code:

```cs
UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
HMACSHA512 hmac = new HMACSHA512(encoding.GetBytes("secret")); // init the HMAC hash with "secret" as a byte array
byte[] hash = hmac.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes("foo")); // hash the payload
String result = Convert.ToBase64String(hash); // Base64 encode the payload
```

The incorrect hash & base64 result:

`gt9xA96Ngt5F4BxF/mQrXRPGwrR97K/rwAlDHGZcb6Xz0a9Ol46hvekUJmIgc+vqxho0Ye/UZ+CXHHiLyOvbvg==`

The expected hash & base64 result:

`ODJkZjcxMDNkZThkODJkZTQ1ZTAxYzQ1ZmU2NDJiNWQxM2M2YzJiNDdkZWNhZmViYzAwOTQzMWM2NjVjNmZhNWYzZDFhZjRlOTc4ZWExYmRlOTE0MjY2MjIwNzNlYmVhYzYxYTM0NjFlZmQ0NjdlMDk3MWM3ODhiYzhlYmRiYmU=`

Comment: If you are not generating the "expected" result, you must be getting it from somewhere else.  Where are seeing this?

Comment: @dana
I've got a node.js program and a php program producing the correct hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since second version is just Base64 of Hex representation you need to convert byte array to hex first and than Base64 ASCII version of the string.

Steps:

- [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)
- [C# Convert a string to ASCII bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490507/c-sharp-convert-a-string-to-ascii-bytes)
- [Conversion from byte array to base64 and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634237/conversion-from-byte-array-to-base64-and-back)

Comment: This was it. I had seen the questions you referenced, but it didn't make sense that it was relevant until you said that I needed to convert the byte[] to hex first. Thank you.